# 2 Separate batchable jobs or 1 combined one?

Tags: apex, batch, scheduled-apex

I have a batch job which runs overnight, which currently only uses the Opportunity object. I now have a need to run the same process for the Order object. How would I do that - do I need to create 2 separate batch jobs or is it possible to do it in 1, using a different query for each object? Basically my (shortened) batchable class is as below, and when it finishes the Oppty run it needs to run the exact same process, but using the Order object instead.

```
global class OpportunityStatusCheck implements Database.Batchable<SObject> {

global Database.queryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
    String query = 'Select Id, Name, etc FROM Opportunity ' +
        ' WHERE ForecastCategory = \'Pipeline\' AND StageName <> \'CAPEX\' AND StageName <> \'Prospecting\' ' ;

    return Database.getQueryLocator(query);        
}

global void execute(Database.BatchableContext BC, List<sObject> scope) {

    List<Opportunity> oppList = (List<Opportunity>)scope;        
    OrgWideEmailAddress[] owea = [select Id from OrgWideEmailAddress where Address = 'noreply@xyz.co.nz'];

    //Get the active users for sending emails to the sales reps and managers 
    List<User> users = [Select Id, email, managerId From User where isActive = True];
    Map<Id, User> mapUsers = new Map<Id, User>();        
    for(User u : users){
        mapUsers.Put(u.Id, u);
    }       

    //get a Map of all Tasks related to this Opportunity for Status = RED
    List<Task> tasks = [Select Id, ActivityDate, ReminderDateTime, WhatId, Status from Task Where Status <> 'Completed' AND WhatId in:oppList];
    Map<Id, Task> mapTasks = new Map<Id, Task>();
    Map<Id, Task> updTasks = new Map<Id, Task>();
    string oldStage;
    Id oldFollowup;

    for(Task t : tasks){
        mapTasks.Put(t.Id,t);
    }

    //get a Map of all Product Lines related to this Opportunity - used in creating the Follow up Tasks
    List<OpportunityLineItem> oplines = [Select OpportunityId, ProductCode, Product2.Name, Quantity, UnitPrice, Description from OpportunityLineItem Where LineType__c = 'Product' AND  OpportunityId in:oppList];
    Map<Id, Set<OpportunityLineItem>> mapFolupProds = new Map<Id, Set<OpportunityLineItem>>();
    Id opId;
    Set<OpportunityLineItem> soli;
    if(oplines.size()>0){
        for(OpportunityLineItem oli : oplines){
            if(oli.OpportunityId != opId){
                //if there's a new Opp, add the existing set and OppId to the Map and create a new set of line items
                mapFolupProds.put(opId, soli);
                opId = oli.OpportunityId;
                soli = new Set<OpportunityLineItem>();
            }
            soli.add(oli);
        }    
        //Add the last entry into the map
        mapFolupProds.put(opId, soli);
    }
    //get a map of Contact sobjects
    List<Contact> contacts = [Select Id, AccredoId__c, Name, Email, MobilePhone, Phone From Contact 
                              Where Id In (Select PrimaryContact__c from Opportunity Where Id In :oppList)];
    Map<string, Contact> mapContacts = new Map<string, Contact>();
    for(Contact c : contacts){
        mapContacts.Put(c.AccredoID__c, c);
    }

    //for updating Opportunity
    List<Opportunity> updOpps = new List<Opportunity>();
    List<Messaging.Email> lstEmails = new List<Messaging.Email>();

    for (Opportunity o : oppList) {
        Opportunity opp = new Opportunity();           
        if(o.Opportunity_Status__c =='x'){
            //do stuff
            }
        }


    }

    if(updOpps.size() > 0){
        update updOpps;
    }
    if(updTasks.size() > 0){
        update updTasks.values();   
    }
    Database.DMLOptions dmlo = new Database.DMLOptions();
    dmlo.EmailHeader.triggerUserEmail = true;
    Messaging.sendEmail(lstEmails);
}

global void finish(Database.BatchableContext BC) {
}
```

}

Comment: Move your logic into a more general purpose service class/method.

Comment: Do you mean the 'execute' section? I can do that, but how does that help me with the 'start' query in doing 2 separate queries, which is the main thing I'm not sure of how to do?

Comment: when the schedulable class instantiates the Batchable class, pass the query in as a value to the constructor rather than hardcoding it in the batchable class; you'll need two schedulable classes

Answer (score 2):

Your "start" method can only return one type of data at a time, assuming you want it to not be limited by the generic query limit of 50,000 rows. Most likely you'll want two separate classes, one for each type, which lets you schedule them independently. If you were concerned about contention between the two, you could also have the first call the second by way of "chaining":

```
global void finish(Database.BatchableContext context) {
    Database.executeBatch(OrderStatusCheck());
}
```

Or, you might create a common base class that performs most of the logic, with two specialty classes that differ in implementation:

```
global abstract BatchStatusCheck implements Database.Batchable<SObject> {
    protected abstract String getQuery();
    protected abstract void process(SObject[] records);

    protected Users[] activeUsers;

    global Database.QueryLocator start(Database.BatchableContext context) {
        return Database.getQueryLocator(getQuery());
    }
    global void execute(Database.BatchableContext context, SObject[] records) {
        activeUsers = [SELECT Email, ManagerId FROM User WHERE IsActive = TRUE];
        // Other pre-processing tasks here
        // Finally, process 
        process(records);
    }
    global void finish(Database.BatchableContext context) {
    }
}
```

Your implementation classes, then, would provide the additional logic:

```
global class OpportunityStatusCheck extends BatchStatusCheck {
    protected override String getQuery() {
        return 'SELECT ...';
    }
    protected void process(SObject[] records) {
        Opportunity[] opps = (Opportunity[])records;
        // rest of logic here
    }
}
```

The primary advantage is that you can build out the parent class to do most of the generic stuff, like querying the tasks, users, org-wide addresses, etc, and make them available to the abstract methods, as demonstrated. This would allow you to still schedule them independently while minimizing duplicate code.

Comment: That sounds like a good plan - will implement and come back here once tested. Thanks!